# SQL: How to return just 1 previous date for a record, not all previous dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a very simple table of ID's and Sign-in dates and I want to use SQL to make a column that shows the previous sign-in date:

```
Table: SIGNIN

| ID     | Sign-in Date |
| A      | 01/01/19     |
| B      | 01/01/19     |
| C      | 02/01/19     |
| A      | 02/01/19     |
| A      | 03/01/19     |
| B      | 03/01/19     |
| A      | 04/01/19     |
| C      | 04/01/19     |
| B      | 05/01/19     |
```

I've tried doing a join to itself but it's showing all previous sign-in dates rather than just the most recent.

```
SELECT [SIGNIN].ID
       [SIGNIN].SignInDate

FROM [SIGNIN]

INNER JOIN [SIGNIN] as [Prev] on  [SIGNIN].ID         = [Prev].ID
                              and [SIGNIN].SignInDate < [Prev].SignInDate

ORDER BY [SIGNIN].ID, [SIGNIN].SignInDate
```

The result I want:

```
Table: SIGNIN

| ID     | Sign-in Date | Previous  |
| A      | 01/01/19     | NULL      |
| B      | 01/01/19     | NULL      |
| C      | 02/01/19     | NULL      |
| A      | 02/01/19     | 01/01/19  |
| A      | 03/01/19     | 02/01/19  |
| B      | 03/01/19     | 01/01/19  |
| A      | 04/01/19     | 03/01/19  |
| C      | 04/01/19     | 02/01/19  |
| B      | 05/01/19     | 03/01/19  |
```

What I'm getting:

```
| ID     | Sign-in Date | Previous  |
| A      | 01/01/19     | NULL      |
| B      | 01/01/19     | NULL      |
| C      | 02/01/19     | NULL      |
| A      | 02/01/19     | 01/01/19  |
| A      | 03/01/19     | 01/01/19  |
| A      | 03/01/19     | 02/01/19  |
| B      | 03/01/19     | 01/01/19  |
| A      | 04/01/19     | 01/01/19  |
| A      | 04/01/19     | 02/01/19  |
| A      | 04/01/19     | 03/01/19  |
| C      | 04/01/19     | 02/01/19  |
| B      | 05/01/19     | 01/01/19  |
| B      | 05/01/19     | 03/01/19  |
```

I'm certain this has been answered elsewhere before, but the biggest problem I'm having is not knowing how to word my problem!

EDIT: Really helpful responses so far, but is there a solution where I can change the date "cut-off" eg:

```
Cut off: 03/01/19
Table: The same
Desired result:

| ID     | Sign-in Date | Previous  |
| A      | 03/01/19     | 02/01/19  |
| B      | 03/01/19     | 01/01/19  |
| A      | 04/01/19     | 03/01/19  |
| C      | 04/01/19     | 02/01/19  |
| B      | 05/01/19     | 03/01/19  |
```

Comment: Three joins is the classical solution. The more modern one is RANK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that if you need to do that it's better to make an ordering column like:

`SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SignInDate) AS O FROM [SIGNIN]`

So the end result would be like:

`SELECT t.ID, t.SignInDate [Sign-In Date], t2.SignInDate as Previous
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SignInDate) AS O FROM [SIGNIN]) t
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY SignInDate) AS O FROM [SIGNIN]) t2 ON t.ID = t2.ID AND t.O = t2.O+1`

Which should give Something akin to:

`A  2019-01-01  NULL
 A  2019-01-04  2019-01-01
 A  2019-02-01  2019-01-04
 B  2019-01-01  NULL
 B  2019-01-05  2019-01-01
 C  2019-01-01  NULL`

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the solution I ended up using, just added a: "WHERE t.SignInDate >= 20190103" 
to the bottom to get my cut-off working

Answer (score 1):

Try using LAG assuming you're on a modern version of SQL Server.

```
SELECT [SIGNIN].ID,
       [SIGNIN].SignInDate,
       LAG([SIGNIN].SignInDate) OVER (PARTITION BY [SIGNIN].ID ORDER BY [SIGNIN].SignInDate DESC) AS Previous

FROM [SIGNIN]
```

Comment: In this case I'm not sure it makes a difference as it will get the same preceding date whatever, it doesn't matter which row it comes from. However the point stands that you'd need more terms in the order if you wanted to point to the last row id and there were multiple for one day.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

> ```
> SELECT 
> ID, SignInDate, 
> LAG(SignInDate, 1,SignInDate) OVER(order by ID partition by ID)
> FROM SIGNIN
> ```

Comment: I think you've missed PARTITION BY. If I'm reading the expected results correctly the lag needs to function within each ID not across all of them.

Comment: Exactly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

using this:

```
SELECT  [SIGNIN].ID,
        [SIGNIN].SignInDate,
        MAX([Prev].SignInDate) as Previous


FROM [SIGNIN]

LEFT JOIN [SIGNIN] as [Prev] on  [SIGNIN].ID         = [Prev].ID
                              and [SIGNIN].SignInDate > [Prev].SignInDate
GROUP BY [SIGNIN].ID, [SIGNIN].SignInDate
ORDER BY [SIGNIN].ID, [SIGNIN].SignInDate
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you almost what you are looking for, just without the nulls.
You should probably do a left outer or right outer join in the inner query, and some extra maneuver  to add the null rows as well. I am a lit

```
select id, max(prev) as prev, signindate from
(
SELECT SIGNIN.ID,
       SIGNIN.SignInDate as prev,
       prev.signindate
FROM SIGNIN
 JOIN SIGNIN as Prev on  SIGNIN.ID         = Prev.ID
                              and SIGNIN.SignInDate < Prev.SignInDate
ORDER BY SIGNIN.ID, SIGNIN.SignInDate 
) a 

group by 1,3
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the `APPLY` solution because you can add any amount of columns from the matching row(s):

```
DECLARE @CutOffDate DATE = '2019-01-03'

SELECT 
    S.ID,
    S.SignInDate,
    PreviousSignInDate = R.SignInDate
FROM 
    [SIGNIN] AS S
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1
            P.* -- Can incorporate many columns (will also have to add them on the outmost SELECT list)
        FROM
            SIGNIN AS P
        WHERE
            S.ID = P.ID AND
            P.SignInDate < S.SignInDate
        ORDER BY
            P.SignInDate DESC
        ) AS R
WHERE
    S.SignInDate >= @CutOffDate
ORDER BY
    S.SignInDate,
    S.ID
```

For this case, you can use `TOP 1` + `ORDER BY` to fetch the previous one, as long as you have the link `S.ID = P.ID` and making sure that `P.SignInDate < S.SignInDate`.

Also get used to writing dates on the `YYYY-MM-DD` format, since `03/01/19` might lead to confusions.

Answer (score 0):

A correlated subquery is a very simple solution :

```
SELECT ID, SignInDate,
       (SELECT top 1 SigInDate
        FROM SIGNIN as S2
        WHERE S2.ID = S1.ID and S2.SignInDate < S1.SignInDate
        ORDER BY S2.SignInDate desc) as Previous
FROM SIGNIN as S1
ORDER BY S1.ID, S1.SignInDate
```